# why u-boot source code remove while compiling?

Tags: yocto, u-boot, pyro

I am perorming following steps for compiling source code locally. i am using  poky version pyro of yocto. but after successfully clean the source code, while compiling  source code is remove and error is display.

step 1 
bitbake -v -c clean u-boot

step 2

bitbake -v u-boot

------------------------------Eroor-------------------------------

make: *** No rule to make target 'am335x_boneblack_config'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/u-boot/u-boot_v2017.01/u-boot_src'

ERROR: u-boot-1_2017.01-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: u-boot-1_2017.01-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /PYRO_BUILD/tmp/work/beaglebone-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2017.01-r0/temp/log.do_compile.10915)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /PYRO_BUILD/tmp/work/beaglebone-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2017.01-r0/temp/log.do_compile.10915

---

how should i resolve it?

Comment: Can you show the recipe file of u-boot-1_2017.01-r0.bb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> make: *** No rule to make target 'am335x_boneblack_config'. Stop.
>   make: Leaving directory
>   '//src_bsp/u-boot/u-boot_v2017.01/u-boot_src'

From above error, It seems that you have uboot code locally at '//u-boot/u-boot_v2017.01/u-boot_src' which gets deleted on compiling(bitbake -v u-boot).

Try using EXTERNALSRC instead of S to specify path to u-boot source code as follows :

```
inherit externalsrc                                                             
EXTERNALSRC = "/<workspace>/u-boot/u-boot_v2017.01/u-boot_src"                                    
EXTERNALSRC_BUILD = "/<workspace>/u-boot/u-boot_v2017.01/u-boot_src"
```